# Usage of "so that he can" vs "so that he may"

Tags: modal-verbs

> 1. He goes to London every month so that he **may see** his ailing father.

> 2. He goes to London every month so that he **can see** his ailing father.

Which one is correct? If both are correct, what is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: A better title would be `usage of can vs may`. I don't see any difference, just like `Can I see him` same as `May I see him`

Comment: @SonNguyen In your example, there is a difference in that _May_ is a more polite way of making the request.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, there is really no difference in meaning between *so that he can* and *so that he may*. You could even avoid the issue by saying that he goes to London  *to see* his father.